# Ajax Class Efficiency

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, object-oriented, ajax

So I wrote this class to handle my ajax calls simply:

**ajaxCon.php:**

```
class ajaxCon{
    private $init = false;
    private $functionArray = array();
    private $Message = false;
    private $function = null;
    private $arguments = null;
    private $post = null;

    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($_POST['ajaxRequest'], $_POST['ajaxFunction'])) return;
        $this->init = true;
        ob_start();
        $this->post = $this->sanitizeArr($_POST);
        $this->arguments = $this->sanitizeArr($_POST['arguments']);
        $this->function = $_POST['ajaxFunction'];
    }

    public function addFunction($functionName, $functionCode){
        if(!$this->init || !isset($functionName, $functionCode) || $functionName != $this->function) return $this;
        $this->Message = call_user_func_array($functionCode, $this->arguments) ? 'success' : 'fail' ;
        unset($this->init, $this->functionArray, $this->post);
        $returnVars = get_object_vars($this);
        ob_clean();
        echo json_encode($returnVars);
        ob_flush();
        exit();
    }

    private function sanitizeArr($returnArr, $sanitizer = 'sanitize_sql_string') {
        array_walk_recursive($returnArr, function (&$value) use ($sanitizer) {
            $value = $sanitizer($value);
        });

        return $returnArr;
    }
}
```

**ajaxCon.js:**

```
function ajax() {

    this.callback = false;

    this.ajaxFailure = function (returnData) {};

    this.ajaxSuccess = function (returnData) {};

    this.call = function(functionName, argumentArray, callback){
        $.ajax( $.extend(true, {}, this.ajaxSettings, {data:{'ajaxFunction':functionName, 'arguments':argumentArray}} ) );
        this.callback = callback;
    };

    this.ajaxReturn = function (returnData){
        returnData = returnData.substring(returnData.indexOf("{") - 1);
        returnData = returnData.substring(0, returnData.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);
        var responseArray = $.parseJSON(returnData);

        if (responseArray.Message.toLowerCase() != "success"){
            this.ajaxFailure(responseArray);
            return;
        }

        this.ajaxSuccess(responseArray);
        if(this.callback != false) this.callback(responseArray);
    };

    window.ajaxCon = this;
    this.ajaxSettings = { url: window.location.href, type: 'POST', cache: false, data: {ajaxRequest: true}, success: function (returnData) {
        ajaxCon.ajaxReturn(returnData)
    }};
}
```

and you call it like so:

```
<?php
    $ajaxCon = new ajaxCon;

    $ajaxCon->addFunction('checkEmail', function($Email){
        global $ajaxCon;
        if(emailIsInDB($Email)) $ajaxCon->hasAccount = true;
        return true;
    });
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxCon = new ajaxCon();

    function checkEmail() {
        ajaxCon.call('checkEmail', {'Email':$('#Email').val()}, function(result){
            if(!result.hasAccount) $('#SignUp').submit();
        });
    }
</script>
```

The drawbacks I know of are lot's of preprocessing (The entire page has to be preprocesed) and the page then executes as normal until the php function I need is defined and called.

Any ideas on how I can optimize the code and make it run more efficiently while preserving/improving readability?

Comment: Take a look at how [swagger](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-js) does it. It's basically a contract for publishing metadata about restful services, sort of like SOAP's WSDL. Might give you some ideas (or you could just go with something like restler php + swagger js client and scrap this code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A review of the JavaScript part:

- `ajaxCon` is a class/constructor, so you should call it `AjaxCon`, though really I would think about finding an even better name :)
- `ajaxFailure` -> You have a number of functions that have `ajax` in their name, since these functions are in the `Ajax` constructor you can drop the `ajax` part
- `this.callback = false;` -> Don't declare callback at all and then use 
  `if(this.callback) this.callback(responseArray);`
- This could use some newlines:
  `$.ajax( $.extend(true, {}, this.ajaxSettings, {data:{'ajaxFunction':functionName, 'arguments':argumentArray}} ) );`

  and also

  ```
  this.ajaxSettings = { url: window.location.href, type: 'POST', cache: false, data: {ajaxRequest: true}, success: function (returnData) {
      ajaxCon.ajaxReturn(returnData)
  }};
  ```
- Also the location of `this.ajaxSettings` is odd, this belongs on top of that function

Comment: I'd mention that `.call` is a poor method name choice in javascript at first glance it meant `Function.prototype.call`

Answer (score 2):

Review for the PHP part:

- What problem does your class solve? Are you not doing too many things in one class? If your goal is to handle incoming Ajax requests, then **a different object** should handle the response.
- Class names should be in CamelCaps, i.e. `AjaxCon`.
- If you need something in your constructor (data from POST, etc), just ask for it in the constructor:

  ```
   public function __construct(array $post) {
  ```
- Don't try to sanitize the entire `$_POST` array at once, it never works. What are you sanitizing it for? Data that goes into the database should go through **[prepared statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)**, data that gets outputted back to the page as HTML should be run through **[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://devdocs.io/php/function.htmlspecialchars)** ***before they are outputted to the page***. Don't sanitize data until the moment you need it, otherwise you risk *double sanitation problems* (`Tom & Jerry` becomes `Tom &amp; Jerry` which becomes `Tom &amp;amp; Jerry`, oops).
- Don't output in your function. Always `return`. Output should be on a single place only, and that's at the very end of the run, where you need to return the response after all processing is done.
- Don't use `get_object_vars($this)` for the purpose you are using it. Specify exactly what variables you are returning, it's more readable.
- **Don't use globals** - If you need to pass a variable from the outside to an anonymous function, use `use`:

  ```
   function($email) use ($ajaxCon) {
  ```
- ***DO NOT USE GLOBALS*** - Seriously, don't.